# Python Selenium with ChromeDriver Headless: Fails To Start-- "DevTools request failed"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I've got this running on my Macbook Pro, so in an attempt to transfer it to my server for prolonged use, I have run into a snag.  Server is Ubuntu 16.04 (server) and Python 2.7.12.

I installed the latest version of selenium using pip, and the latest version of ChromeDriver. I can start it fine from the command line (there is a GPU error but it seems not to cause any problems.)

However, when I try to start it from within python, using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

path_to_chromedriver = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 
service_args = ['--verbose']
service_log_path = '/tmp/local/chromedriver.log'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver, chrome_options=options, service_args=service_args, service_log_path=service_log_path)
```

However, when I start things up, here's what I get in the chromedriver.log (after all the initial startup script for COMMAND InitSession:

```
[0.998][INFO]: Launching chrome: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-ap\
ps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-automation --enable-logging --ign\
ore-certificate-errors --load-extension=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.tPkUXa/internal --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basi\
c --remote-debugging-port=12752 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.ODIHcL\
 data:,
[0.998][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12752/json/version
[1.078][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
```

And it continues to spit out that error message for about 60 seconds until it ultimately returns this in Python:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64)
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to fix this, and I have searched extensively.

I was under the impression that I didn't need to use any virtual screen emulation if I was using headless, but could that be the issue?  (I'm running in an init mode w/o a GUI in Ubuntu.)

Also, I don't like that there's no --headless being passed in that command to start chrome-stable... is that an issue?

Thanks.

EDITS:

Chromedriver version (I got what I thought was latest version):

```
$ chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver 2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

Selenium

```
$ pip freeze | grep selenium
selenium==3.11.0
```

Chrome

```
$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 65.0.3325.162
```

Here's the log trace that shows what's going on-- it loops on the DevTools failure for 60 seconds then dies.

```
Full log/error trace:
[0.997][INFO]: COMMAND InitSession {
   "capabilities": {
      "alwaysMatch": {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [ "start-maximized", "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-extensions", "--no-sandbox" ],
            "extensions": [  ]
         },
         "platformName": "any"
      },
      "firstMatch": [ {

      } ]
   },
   "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
         "args": [ "start-maximized", "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-extensions", "--no-sandbox" ],
         "extensions": [  ]
      },
      "platform": "ANY",
      "version": ""
   }
}
[0.997][INFO]: Populating Preferences file: {
   "alternate_error_pages": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "autofill": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "browser": {
      "check_default_browser": false
   },
   "distribution": {
      "import_bookmarks": false,
      "import_history": false,
      "import_search_engine": false,
      "make_chrome_default_for_user": false,
      "show_welcome_page": false,
      "skip_first_run_ui": true
   },
   "dns_prefetching": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "profile": {
      "content_settings": {
         "pattern_pairs": {
            "https://*,*": {
               "media-stream": {
                  "audio": "Default",
                  "video": "Default"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "default_content_setting_values": {
         "geolocation": 1
      },
      "default_content_settings": {
         "geolocation": 1,
         "mouselock": 1,
         "notifications": 1,
         "popups": 1,
         "ppapi-broker": 1
      },
      "password_manager_enabled": false
   },
   "safebrowsing": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "search": {
      "suggest_enabled": false
   },
   "translate": {
      "enabled": false
   }
}
[0.997][INFO]: Populating Local State file: {
   "background_mode": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "ssl": {
      "rev_checking": {
         "enabled": false
      }
   }
}
[0.998][INFO]: Launching chrome: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-automation --enable-logging --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.tPkUXa/internal --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12752 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.ODIHcL data:,
[0.998][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12752/json/version
[1.078][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
...
[61.018][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12752/json/version
[61.018][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[61.021][INFO]: RESPONSE InitSession unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
[61.021][DEBUG]: Log type 'driver' lost 0 entries on destruction
[61.021][DEBUG]: Log type 'browser' lost 0 entries on destruction
```

Comment: Looks like you're using an old version of chromedriver. Try updating chromedriver (and selenium while you're at it).

Comment: Also, start `start-maximized` with `--`.

Comment: Can you update the question with the complete error stack trace along with the version info of the binaries you are using?

Comment: Alright-- added trace, library/binary versions.

Comment: I'm a complete idiot.  You were right @sytech I updated to the latest and that fixed it.  Note to anybody who may find this-- MAKE SURE YOU USE THE LATEST VERSION AND DON'T COPY PASTE FROM AN OLD TUTORIAL!

Comment: I am getting this same problem, even with the latest chromedriver (2.37, as of this writing) and Chrome 65, also on Ubuntu 16.04 ...

Answer (score 2):

Your chromedriver is out of date for your version of chrome. You're using `chromedriver=2.29.461571` but the latest version of chromedriver, which is compatible with Chrome65 is `2.37`

You can find the latest chromedriver for your platform here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Answer (score 0):

The answer was-- use the latest version of chromedriver!

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

I copy/pasted from what I thought was a up to date script and it was too old a version.